# How to check identical of dictionary key values?

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi I am trying to do simple task of Python whether the dictionary's keys are equal or not. 
here is my example code

```
loc = {'latitude' :-90.0, 'longitude' : -180.0, 'timestamp': 1512531206, 'name': "SNU",  'keywords':["school, hard"],}
```

This is my example data. And if I print out the loc's key values, then I got...

```
print(loc.keys())
```

Print: dict_keys(['latitude', 'longitude', 'timestamp', 'name', 'keywords'])

So what I wanted to do is checking whether the data is same as dictionary's key or not. I use this but it does not work at all....

```
print(loc.keys() == ['latitude', 'longitude', 'timestamp', 'name', 'keywords'])
```

This still gets me False. Is there any other way that I can make this into false?

Comment: `[key for key in loc if key in ['latitude', 'longitude', 'timestamp', 'name', 'keywords']]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, `.keys` returns a view that behaves just like a set. You just need to change 2 characters - the brackets - to make your list literal into a *`set`* literal:

```
>>> loc = {'latitude' :-90.0, 'longitude' : -180.0, 'timestamp': 1512531206, 
'name': "SNU",  'keywords':["school, hard"],}
>>> loc.keys() == {'latitude', 'longitude', 'timestamp', 'name', 'keywords'}
True
```

IF you want to ensure that the dictionary has *at least* these keys, use `.issubset` / `.issuperset`. Unfortunately the key view does not have these method so you need to use it on the set. For example

```
>>> {'latitude', 'longitude'}.issubset(loc.keys())
True
>>> {'latitude', 'foobar'}.issubset(loc.keys())
False
```

Note that you don't even need to use `.keys()` in this case:

```
>>> {'latitude', 'longitude'}.issubset(loc)
True
```

Answer (score 5):

Dictionaries are unordered data structures, and `dict.keys()` returns a View object, not a list so a simple comparison of the keys against a list won't work. Fortunately, the View object is set-like, and you can use set operations on it. For example,

```
loc = {
    'latitude' :-90.0, 'longitude' : -180.0, 'timestamp': 1512531206, 
    'name': "SNU",  'keywords':["school, hard"],
}

print(loc.keys() == {'latitude', 'longitude', 'timestamp', 'name', 'keywords'})
```

**output**

```
True
```

---

In CPython 3.6+ dicts *do* retain insertion order, but that's currently an implementation detail, and we aren't supposed to rely on it. But apart from that, the dict's items may have been inserted in any order, so it's not a good idea to assume that the keys will be in a particular order.

Comment: @shash678 nope. Dictionaries are still officially unordered. They *happen* to maintain insertion order, but that is an implementation detail (although it will likely become part of the spec on python 3.7+)

Comment: @shash678 Well, yes,  in Python 3.6+ dicts _do_ retain insertion order, but that's currently an implementation detail, and we aren't supposed to rely on it. But apart from that, the dict's items may have been inserted in any order, so it's not a good idea to assume that the keys will be in a particular order.

Comment: @PM2Ring correction: in CPython 3.6. We don't yet know anything about other Python 3.6's :D

Answer (score 1):

Just convert list of keys to set and compare with another set:

```
set(loc.keys()) == {'latitude', 'longitude', 'timestamp', 'name', 'keywords'}
```

As @juanpa.arrivillaga kindly noted you don't need to get `keys()` of dict to convert the into `set`, you can do it right away:

```
set(loc) == {'latitude', 'longitude', 'timestamp', 'name', 'keywords'}
```

**NOTE**: To the best answer please refer to @PM2Ring [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47669226/3124746)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you, i've updated answer.:)

Comment: no need to call set ;-) , see other answers. My guess would be that `loc.keys()` is faster because it returns a view unlike `set(loc)` which I presume has to copy the keys.

Comment: @PaulPanzer oh, thank you, totally forgot about that. Would not put that in answer, but instead make reference to PM2Ring answer.